# Undo migration to AndroidX

Tags: android, android-studio

I've refactored my Android Studio codebase to AndroidX successfully. But it is causing a few problems with some of my libraries.

I need to revert it since the app is going into production soon. How can I do it?

Comment: Roll back to the previous version in your version control system. Or, unpack the backup that the AndroidX migration wizard offered to you.

Comment: Just in case, If you want to improve the errors, go through the docs of AndroidX and try to solve it.

Answer (score 20):

I had gone through the same, Follow the steps to undo the AndroidX Migration:

1. Remove following lines in `gradle.properties`:

   ```
   android.enableJetifier=true
   android.useAndroidX=true
   ```
2. Remove AndroidX dependencies in `build.gradle` of your app and replace them with their equivalent Non AndroidX dependencies:

   e.g.

   ```
   implementation 'androidx.core:core:1.0.0-beta01'
   implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-beta01'
   ```
3. Sync Project with Gradle Files
4. After syncing you may have import errors in java files, you can remove the androidx imports and re add the equivalent non androidx imports

I hope it will help everyone facing migration rollback problem. If you get any conflict issues while performing above steps in Android Studio, try to clean and rebuild the project.

Comment: Isn't there any easier solution as there will be more than 100+ files and doing it manually would be a tedious task.

Comment: @sanjeev Android Studio always asks to create a backup (zip) before migrating to AndroidX, if you have the backup file, no need to follow above steps. And you can always rollback to older stable branch in your version control system.

Comment: You are right. That should help for a user taking precautions unless they edit the code afterwards.. :) But i think they should also bring a rollback to previous option so it would be easier.

Comment: it will work correctly but this would be so easier to use backup file (if you accept android studio to create backup before migrate to androidX)

Answer (score 5):

You can simply choose `Migrate App to appCompat` from `Refactor` menu in Android Studio.

Also, don't forget to delete these lines from `gradle.properties`:

```
android.useAndroidX=true
```

```
android.enableJetifier=true
```

Comment: "migrate App to appCompat" is not the opposite of migrate to androidx, it simply uses appcompat imports from androidx rather than non-appcompat ones

Comment: @davkutalek please what is the answer then

Comment: @Pfil There isn't any easy way that I know of. Reverting in your version control or manually changing the imports back are the only way I know of. If you revert you may need to clear your cache

Comment: @davkutalekI think this is the best solution, what is the difference between appcompat and androidx? the code is 100% the same, so just the libraries,  therefore if you choose "migrate App to appCompat" the libraries and imports revert back to using appcompat.

Answer (score 2):

I couldn't simply roll back in version control, because the app I wanted to roll back was `androidx` from its initial commit, but I was tasked with integrating the app module into a larger project without `androidx`.

Here's what I did:

1. Try syncing gradle and inevitably you'll get some kind of error. Here is the first error I saw:

> Error: Attribute application@appComponentFactory
>   value=(androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory) from
>   [**androidx.core:core:1.1.0**] AndroidManifest.xml:24:18-86 is also
>   present at [com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0]
>   AndroidManifest.xml:22:18-91
>   value=(android.support.v4.app.CoreComponentFactory)

2. Take note of the `androidx` package in the above error.
3. Run `gradlew dependencies` inside the module you're trying to migrate back.
4. Search the output for the `androidx` package mentioned in the above error. Figure out which of your dependencies from your `build.gradle` file is bringing in that package, then revert that package to its equivalent [support library mapping](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/artifact-mappings).
5. Repeat steps 1-4 until Gradle sync finishes successfully.
6. Now you need to search all your `.java` files for `androidx` and replace each import statement with its [support library package name](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/artifact-mappings). **Tip for this step**: turn on "Add unambiguous imports on the fly" in Android Studio preferences and just delete all the `androidx` imports. Most of them will auto-repopulate with the correct support packages.
7. Now your project should build successfully, but you'll likely run into runtime crashes due to `androidx` view components used in layout files.
8. Search all xml files for `androidx` and `com.google.android.material`, and replace each view with its support equivalent name.
9. Don't forget to fix any compilation issues in your tests, and re-run them to make sure they still all pass.

Comment: Can't find where i'm using this... '''androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0'''. Certanly not in build.gradle because I roll it back before the migration. "@Override's" ??

Answer (score 0):

Do a hard reset on repository which was working before migration to android x.

Delete the `node_modules` folder, and type `npm install`.